Drug use and legality
I flagged a recent question and I merely stated 'drug use and legality'. My flag was declined.
May I request, therefore, a statement from SE-Christianity whether drug use is to be discussed on SE-C irrespective of the fact that many countries have laws which prohibit use of illegal drugs.
I had expected that any mention or discussion of drug use would be moderated in regard to the variety of judicial responses in different countries.

I just checked recent questions, but I couldn't find any questions about drug use and legality. It seems it has been closed and/or deleted? What was the decline reason? Was it to use a standard flag?

@AndrewT. Link. Yes, it has been closed.

To my understanding that post was made by someone who was being dishonest and looking for trouble. Though I did dig into their side of things further, they have things to work through. But your question is a good one. I personally believe on a religious ground, the subject is perfectly okay. Plants and things are part of the creation God gave us. It is the abuse of things that is evil, not the substance. Sugar is bad for you if you ultra refine it, same is true for cocaine. The religious conversation about how to "respect your body as the temple of God" is valid and not off topic. Imho.
